# Selenium always giving stale element

Tags: java, selenium, exception

I have been using 
`wait.until(ExpectedConditions.presenceOfElementLocated(By.id("some_id_here")));`

and

```
wait.until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By.id("some_id_here")));
```

to try to avoid StaleElementReferenceExceptions, but they keep getting thrown.

I believe the page is refreshing these elements but the way I am calling for these elements is like this:

```
public static WebElement login_btn(WebDriver driver, WebDriverWait wait) {
        wait.until(ExpectedConditions.presenceOfElementLocated(By.id("btnEntrar")));
        wait.until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By.id("btnEntrar")));
        element = driver.findElement(By.id("btnEntrar"));
        return element;
}
```

then returning the element and using it, so in theory it should search up the element everytime I use it.

What could also be the reason this exception keeps getting thrown and are there any other methods of avoiding them?

Comment: Summarize this method as `public static WebElement login_btn(WebDriver driver, WebDriverWait wait) {
        return wait.until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By.id("btnEntrar")));
}` and let me know

Comment: can you provide the Stractrace please?